# Trying to Install pytaglib 1.0.3 but Encountering Fatal Error

Tags: macos, python-3.x, installation, osx-yosemite

I'm using Python 3.4 and have the OS X Yosemite (10.10.4). According to the website this version of pytaglib should be compatible.

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pytaglib

I've tried all of the ways of installing as listed on the page and I keep running into the same error.

```
/usr/bin/clang -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -        O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -g -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/include/python3.4m -c src/taglib.cpp -o build/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-3.4/src/taglib.o src/taglib.cpp:268:10: fatal error: 'taglib/tstring.h' file not found
#include "taglib/tstring.h"
     ^
1 error generated.
error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit status 1
AccuDeveloper-iMac:pytaglib-1.0.3 accudeveloper$ sudo ln -s/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk MacOSX10.6.sdk
```

Perhaps it doesn't think I'm using the OS I'm actually using?

Answer (score 5):

Do you have taglib installed?

I got the same error on my machine, but was able to get it working by installing taglib with Homebrew:

```
brew install taglib
sudo pip3 install pytaglib
```

Comment: Nah, I had just given up on it. Ended up using mutagenx 1.24 instead. Which works quite nicely. I tried using pip and easy_install. Perhaps that's why I couldn't get it to work though, I hadn't used sudo or brew.

Thanks for the response!

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I solved the issue 0n OS X 10.11

first install taglib via brew:

```
brew install taglib
```

and then you need to pass the include and library paths into pip install like so:

```
sudo pip install --global-option=build_ext --global-option="-I/usr/local/include/" --global-option="-L/usr/local/lib"  pytaglib
```

after that you should be good to go.

Comment: This allows you to install in virtualenv without sudo as well. Great answer.

Answer (score 1):

An updated version (1.4.1), for those using **macports**.  I was able to get it working on OS X 10.11 with:

`sudo port install taglib`

To find the location of the required files, I used:

`sudo port contents taglib`

and then (in a 3.5 virtual environment):

(ENV)$ `sudo pip install --global-option=build_ext --global-option="-I/opt/local/include/" --global-option="-L/usr/local/lib"  pytaglib`

It didn't seem to care if `--global-option="-L...`  was set to `/usr/local/lib` or `/opt/local/lib`.  Trying both, I still got back "Successfully installed pytaglib-1.4.1".

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem on Linux, you need to install taglib by downloading and extracting taglib-N.NN.tar.gz , extracting and building it as per the INSTALL instructions included, e.g.

cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release .

make

sudo make install

This will put everything in place for PIP to be able to install pytaglib successfully.
The first time I tried to use it I had an taglib.so: undefined symbol error so I built and ran the tests using the option -DBUILD_TESTS=on in cmake and then running:

make check

All the tests passed and everything worked in python after this step.